# I think that a searching-favorite-posts feature is needed

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I want to find a topic in favorite posts. So I think that a searching feature can be added in the future to all communities.

Comment: Favorite-starred != upvoted. Please clarify this feature request - impossible to tell which of the two you mean, given the above.

Comment: You mean *infavorites:mine*?

Comment: You're asking about upvotes, right? Not score? So a question with a score of -10 but 20 upvotes would be in your search result? This is not what you want: [infavorites:6135652 score:10](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A6135652+score%3A10), right?

Comment: @Oded I just noticed. I mean favorite posts. Upvoted posts already displaying in search results as tab.